# Fixing stale state inside useEffect Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have fixed an issue with the useEffect callback using 'stale'/old state values based on closures when react first initialised the state object. Previously, when the `useEffect` callback was executed after mounting, it would only have access to the first state value, which was `null`. I solved this by adding the state object, `isSignedIn` as the second argument to the `useEffect` hook. Now `useEffect` re-runs whenever `changeSignInStatus` is called, meaning that after the first render, the `useEffect` callback is run for the first time, but is subsequently run for a second time with the updated state value. My app therefore then has access to the new state value.

However, I would ideally like to avoid constantly re-running the `useEffect` callback whenever the state object updates, as i dont want to have to re-load the google auth library each time.

Does anyone have an idea of how i can solve the issue of stale state inside the `useEffect` hook without having to place my state object as the second `useEffect` argument?

```
function GoogleAuth(){

    const [isSignedIn,changeSignInStatus] = useState(null);

    var auth

    useEffect(()=>{
        //load client:auth2 library and define a callback
        window.gapi.load('client:auth2',()=>{
            window.gapi.client.init({
                clientId:"*****************************",
                scope:"email"
            }).then(()=>{
                auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                changeSignInStatus(auth.isSignedIn.get());
                auth.isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
            });
        });


    },[isSignedIn]);
```

Comment: WHat stale data you were getting without using isSignedIn in depndency array ?

Comment: `auth` will reinitialize to `undefined` every re-render

Answer (score 0):

Adding it here, because the suggestion is large.

1st question: Which value was becoming stale, when not using isSignedIn in dependency array. ?

2nd as per looking at your code, we can have a fix like this to avoid repeated loading of library:

```
function GoogleAuth() {
  const [isSignedIn, changeSignInStatus] = useState(null);

  var auth;

  useEffect(() => {
    //load client:auth2 library and define a callback
    if (!isSignedIn) {
      window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
        window.gapi.client
          .init({
            clientId: "*****************************",
            scope: "email",
          })
          .then(() => {
            auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            changeSignInStatus(auth.isSignedIn.get());
            auth.isSignedIn.listen(onAuthChange);
          });
      });
    }
  }, [isSignedIn]);
}
```

Let me know what do you think ?